# Is entity framework 6.1 (prerelease) view generation okay to use for production

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've been dealing with EF in my project for 5+ years. It's database-first and because of huge overhead migration to DbContext will result in, I'm still dancing with ObjectContext.
It is nice to see improvements of runtime performance delivered in each release, though we all know that last official release is missing view generation mechanisms because of mapping api been hidden. This is fine for relatively simple entity models, but I'm having a complex one, warm up time is not acceptable. 
I've installed 6.1 beta recently and it looks like generated views do the job, and I'm thinking of making it part of my project's next delivery.
My question is about 6.1 prerelease version: is it beta because of not everything from promised 6.1 backlog is done(were, though, some things are completed and tested) or is it beta because everything to some extent, is still being developed?
I'm hoping for first case scenario and maybe someone can help me with figuring this out, any kind of feedback is welcome(don't tell me "beta is beta", I know :) ).
Thanks!

Comment: See [EF 6.1.0 RTM Available](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/03/17/ef6-1-0-rtm-available.aspx)

Comment: Ah, thanks, didn't see that one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like suggested by @abatishchev, I've installed [EF 6.1.0 RTM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/03/17/ef6-1-0-rtm-available.aspx) instead.